# Loading external scripts

Tags: html

With HTML, you load scripts using `<script></script>` tags with a `src` attribute. For stylesheets and such, you load them with `<link />` tags with a `href` attribute.

As you can see, link tags are empty whereas script tags are not. This seems weird when loading an external script. For example:

`<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>`

To me, it would make more sense loading it in an empty tag. E.g.

`<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" />`

My question is, is there a way to load scripts and such in an empty tag. It's not such a big deal however I am curious.

Comment: You might want to focus on just learning how to do it, rather than arguing with every detail. One reason for the two <script> tags is that there might be JavaScript in them. In that case, you need both an opening tag and a closing tag. So, instead of having the browsers guess, we use two tags. That doesn't happen with <link>.

Comment: @DOK Why not have it work both ways. `<script></script>` when we want to embed the code and `<script />` if we want to load it externally.

Comment: Why not have it work both ways? Because every single browser would have to implement that before you could use it, and that would take a very long time, so you couldn't use it now. Think about the poor bastards who have to write the browser code, and how they would write code for this. "When there is a <script> keep reading possibly thousands of lines of code, parsing it as you go, using the Javascript parser or the jQuery.js or the Backbone.js or....and you finally get to an angle bracket, so is it a closing </script> or a greater than sign or another HTML element? now circle back to <script>

Comment: Here is a recent article on this very subject that you might find helpful. http://www.colorglare.com/2014/02/03/to-close-or-not-to-close.html

Comment: And here is the recent discussing and ranging on Hacker News. https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=7310768

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do this, because imagine that the script tag gets the code from that URL and tries to put it in inbetween its closing tag and opening tag; it cannot do this if it's a void element.

To be more specific, HTML5 has a parsing engine that doesn't allow this.  There are a lot of rules in HTML that you're going to argue, but just go with it.

Answer (score 1):

In HTML 4 terms, no - a script element can have content (an inline script), so it is not defined as EMPTY, so the end tag is mandatory.

In XHTML - yes, but only if you use an XML content-type. It isn't HTML compatible so you cannot use it in a document served as text/html.

In HTML 5 terms, no - HTML 5 is designed to be backwards compatible. No new empty elements are being introduced as older browsers would not know that the end tag needs to be inferred.